# Flash Message Laravel 5.2 using toast materialize

Tags: php, laravel, toast, materialize, flash-message

can you help me solve this problem ? so in this case i want to show flash message in the next page after button click & action (save, update, delete) success perform...

i've read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/materialize/materialize_dialogs.htm and also http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html but idk how to use it in my controller

```
public function hapuskeluhan($id){

    $keluh = keluhan::findOrFail($id);
    $keluh->delete();                
    return redirect('lihatkeluhan');
}
```

For Example is function delete, how could my toast appear before it redirect ? or maybe after ? please kindly help me brother

Comment: My advice is using flash session:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data

Comment: hello @nguyen Thanh i've try that option but unfortunetly its not working for me idk why even its not error could you guide me step by step ? cause maybe there's something that i missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@if(session('message'))
        <script>
          Materialize.toast("{{ @session('message') }}", 5000);  
        </script>

        @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the message along with the redirection to be displayed on the view.

```
public function hapuskeluhan($id)
{
    $keluh = keluhan::findOrFail($id);
    $keluh->delete();                
    return redirect('lihatkeluhan')->with(['message', 'Record Deleted!']);
}
```

and in your view you could access the session variable message as

```
Materialize.toast({{ session('message') }}, duration, 'rounded');
```

and initiate a click so that the toast is displayed

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("your element containing materialize handle").click();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Mohammad Arshad is correct. Thank you.

Just to clarify things, I put my code bellow to communicate the system login.

If you want to work with colors, for example, on login success (green) or login fail (red). Just populate the third parameter of materialize toast with 'green' or 'red' respectively.

On UserController.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Login;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Hash;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $data = $request->all();

        if(Auth::attempt([ 'email'=>$data['email'], 'password'=>$data['password'] ]))
        {

            \Session::flash('message', ['msg'=>'Login done successfully!', 'class'=>'green']);

            return redirect()->route('user.index');

        }

        \Session::flash('message', ['msg'=>'Login failed. Check your data.', 'class'=>'red']);

        return redirect()->route('user.index');

    }

}
```

On site.blade.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>{{ config('site.name', 'YourSite') }}</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('lib/materialize/dist/css/materialize.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            @include('yourHeaderCode._site._nav')
        </header>

        <main>

            <!-- Your main code -->
            @yield('content')

        </main>

        @include('yourFooterCode._site._footer')

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('lib/materialize/dist/js/materialize.js') }}"></script>

        @if(Session::has('message'))
            <script type="text/javascript">
                Materialize.toast("{{ Session::get('message')['msg'] }}", 4000, "{{ Session::get('mensagem')['class'] }}");
            </script>
        @endif()

    </body>
</html>
```